# How to use PHP libraries whithout composer (FPDI with FPDI protection)

Tags: php, composer-php, fpdf, fpdi

I use [FPDI](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI) without composer so my file looks like this:

```
...
use \setasign\Fpdi;
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/fpdi2/src/autoload.php');

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new Fpdi\Fpdi();
...
```

I would like to add [FPDI Protection](https://github.com/Setasign/fpdi-protection) to protect the PDFs I just generated

But on their readme, it shows only the procedure to follow if one uses composer

```
use setasign\FpdiProtection\FpdiProtection;

// setup the autoload function
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$pdf = new FpdiProtection();
$ownerPassword = $pdf->setProtection(
    FpdiProtection::PERM_PRINT | FpdiProtection::PERM_COPY,
    'the user password',
    'the owner password'
);
```

How to make FPDI uninitialized with FPDI Protection? I do not understand how to do ..

Comment: I think you're mistaken: Including the autoloader means you are not using composer.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Even when using composer you must include/require the files one way or another. The `vendor/autoload.php` file, created by Composer, contains the bootstrap to load all files of all vendor packages installed. Checkable via the `composer.lock` file generated at the moment of installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is documented [here](https://github.com/Setasign/fpdi-protection#manual-installation):

> If you do not use composer, just require the autoload.php in the /src folder:
>
> ```
> require_once('src/autoload.php');
> ```
>
> If you have a PSR-4 autoloader implemented, just register the src path as follows:
>
> ```
> $loader = new \Example\Psr4AutoloaderClass;
> $loader->register();
> $loader->addNamespace('setasign\FpdiProtection', 'path/to/src/');
> ```

So in your case, just require both autoload.php files from FPDI and FPDI Protection:

```
use setasign\FpdiProtection\FpdiProtection;

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/fpdi2/src/autoload.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/fpdi_protection/src/autoload.php');

$pdf = new FpdiProtection();
...
```